# How can I parse an URL from the Link module?

Tags: entities, navigation, theming

I am developing a website, my website, powering Drupal 7 and I know that the Link module already has something like displaying a link from http://website.com/some-article-here to website.com but I want to be able to display something like that and to manually add the same field in to a  tag. To sum up, I need the first long link http://website.com/some-article-here provided from the link field to go in an  tag and the parsed one website.com to simply show on the website as it is. Got it? Please help!

Comment: I think that your question is a little too broad. There may be various different answers based on assumptions about how you have built your Drupal site. My assumption is this - you have created a content type, it has a link field, and you want to display the link field in a certain manner. This is actually still too broad as this could be done by as Field Formatter, in a preprocess function, in an alter function, or directly in a php template.

Comment: The way I am reading this; you want to display the parsed url (display: website.com, path: website.com/some-path) what the link module currently offers, but you also want to have a [taxonomy term](https://www.drupal.org/node/774892) (tag) for the long url? And it should be automatically provided with the path value of the link field?

Comment: I know my answer is a bit late, but here is what I want: I have a link field, I need the same Link field to display as the main domain name from the submitted URL value like just website.com and the long version website.com/some-article, which is the default value I enter in the Link field, to have it placed in a <a> tag.